# Spring Stomp message send and receiptId

Tags: spring, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

What is the right way to configure Spring StompBrokerRelay, to be able to create a simple java client which just publishes a messages, which are acknowledge by the server.
Spring client StompSession is returning Receiptable when sending message from client and it's possible to configure ReceiptTasks, but the receipt is never received from server.